# Mule3 Upload attachment to a SFTP server

Tags: ftp, mule, sftp, mulesoft, mule-esb

I want to upload attachments as it is to an SFTP server that got from HTTP inbound. These files can be any type like XML, JSON, txt etc.

I tried these sample codes but the issue is upload files are not in the format, type I sent. It always stored in the FTP server like `1f144250-7b46-11ea-a605-38f9d3744a4d.dat`.

```
    <flow name="FtpUp">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/attach1" doc:name="Copy_of_HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.inboundAttachments.size()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger"/>
        <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="Copy_of_For Each">
            <set-payload value="#[payload.dataSource.content]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
            <set-attachment attachmentName="test.txt" value="#[payload]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attachment"/>
            <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="" port="22" path="" user="" password="" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
    <flow name="Copy_of_FtpUp">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/attach2" doc:name="Copy_of_Copy_of_HTTP"/>
        <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="Copy_of_Copy_of_For Each">
            <set-payload value="#[payload.dataSource.content]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="" port="22" path="" user="" password="" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Copy_of_SFTP" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
        </foreach>
    </flow>
```

[image]

Can someone please help me to figure out the missing part? I just want to upload the file as it is that I'm getting to HTTP inbound. I'm using Mulesoft 3 (3.9.4 EE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that the SFTP outbound endpoint is not setting an [outputPattern](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/sftp-transport-reference#attributes-of-outbound-endpoint) attribute to define the name of the output file. The default value is the message id, which explains the names you are getting.

> outputPattern
>
> The pattern to use when writing a file to disk. This can use the
>   patterns supported by the filename-parser configured for this
>   connector. By default the File Transport Reference is used. See this
>   same document section for information on how to override the default
>   parser.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: The message ID, for example, ee241e68-c619-11de-986b-adeb3d6db038

Also, the flow is sending the files as attachments. The SFTP connector expects the contents of the file to be transferred to be in the payload.

Comment: You are correct and spot on. Once I changed the `outputPattern` everything worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code snippet after following the @aled suggestion.

```
<flow name="FtpUp">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/attach2" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <foreach collection="#[message.inboundAttachments]" doc:name="Iterate attachments ">
        <set-variable variableName="fileName" value="#[payload.dataSource.part.fileName]" doc:name="Set File Name"/>
        <set-payload value="#[payload.dataSource.content]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="" port="22" path="" user="" password="" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP Server" disableTransportTransformer="true" outputPattern="#[flowVars.fileName]"/>
    </foreach>
</flow>
```